# How to configure geoserver in jetty web server with SSL

Tags: jetty, geoserver

I am trying to configure geoserver with SSL but it is not happening. I am using Windows Server 2019.
Configured geoserver it is running fine and available in http://example.com/geoserver/web but not working in https://example.com/geoserver/web

I have created geoserver_ssl.jks which is all fine. I have tested this for the ssl of apache tomcat, it worked. But the same is not working with geoserver.

I modified start.ini and added following lines.

#SSL

— module=ssl

jetty.ssl.port=8443

jetty.sslContext.keyStorePath=C:\geoserver_ssl.jks

jetty.sslContext.trustStorePath=C:\geoserver_ssl.jks

jetty.sslContext.keyStorePassword=password

jetty.sslContext.keyManagerPassword=password

jetty.sslContext.trustStorePassword=password

— module=https

jetty.httpConfig.securePort=8443

I reffered this [`link`](https://monicamohangis.medium.com/installing-ssl-certificate-for-geoserver-jetty-1d325e23e0e1) but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the built in Jetty for anything except basic checking - in production you will want to use either `tomcat` or a **full** install of `jetty`. The one we ship with GeoServer is a cut down old version that is mostly provided as a small test fixture.